# Rocket League Base Game vs Collector's Edition

Tags: version-differences, rocket-league

What is the difference between the Rocket League Base Game and the Collector's Edition? I have bought the Collector's Edition, but could someone please confirm what is included?

Answer (score 6):

Rocket League Collector's Edition contains the following:

- Base game
- Supersonic Fury DLC Pack
- Revenge of the Battle-Cars DLC Pack
- Chaos Run DLC Pack
- Four brand-new vehicles debuting in the Collector’s Edition:

  - Esper (Neo Tokyo-inspired)
  - Masamune (Neo Tokyo-inspired)
  - Aftershock (Homage to the original Supersonic Acrobatic Rocket-Powered Battle-Cars)
  - Marauder (Homage to the original Supersonic Acrobatic Rocket-Powered Battle-Cars)
- Exclusive art print

There are some things that don't come with it still like batman and back to the future but you get a lot for buying the Collector's edition and it's worth it if you don't own the game.

[Here is the wiki for more vehicle information](http://rocketleague.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles).

IF you own the game, it is not worth it and you should buy DLCs in-game yourself if that's what you want out of Collector's.

Comment: But can I win cars that you have to buy in the non-collector's edition?

Comment: No, but since they added their crate system that is a way to win more cars - although you have to buy the keys. I can add the wiki link to my answer so you can see which cars are unlockable, DLC, and crate exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

The Collector's Edition contains the following:

- Base game
- Supersonic Fury DLC Pack
- Revenge of the Battle-Cars DLC
- Pack Chaos Run DLC Pack
- Four other vehicles (as a timed exclusive)